# Add keywords of a language to completion list when selected

Tags: auto-complete-mode

I am using Emacs with auto-complete package. I know that Emacs can auto-detect the language. I would like it to automatically add keywords of the detected language to the completion list, in order to allow me to complete such keywords, even if I just open an empty file.

For example, if launch Emacs with a brand new file `main.c`:

```
$ emacs main.c
```

I would like to be able to auto-complete to `#include` if I write `#inc` .

Comment: [yasnippets](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) for little code snippets and more.

Comment: and [icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)!